# How can I make a tool-tip to automatically appear for my chrome extension which uses pageaction?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to have a message displayed automatically, whenever my pageaction icon is displayed.

How can I make that to be displayed, I want to alert the user that " You can click this button to perform so on....".

Comment: You can change the icon to some alert icon with setIcon method. Or you can blink the icon if you really want to annoy the users. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a popup appear programmatically, this cannot be done, it can only be initiated by a user click.

It would be nice if you could use [infobars API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/infobars), but it is still experimental.

Therefore, your only choice seems to be to inject a script into the page that would create some sort of overlay on the page roughly pointing to the page action area.

Note that you will need permission to access that page, as `activeTab` permission is not enabled until user clicks on your page action.

Comment: Thanks @XAN, very well answered. Thanks!